# Python NoneType or Null Value Checking

Tags: python, null, typeerror, nonetype

I am using python3 requests to pull data down from an API. I then json the response. One of the fields can have a string value or be null. To start with a simple test, I've just been printing the values to screen. However, when the value is null, I can't print because of the NoneType class and it's failing. If I print out the type, I will see "<class 'NoneType'>".

Code below. I am checking if the response is None, and only print out when it's not null. However, when the value for jResponse["variable"] is null or none, I am now receiving an error of `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` and points to the if statement line.

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
jResponse = response.json()

if jResponse["variable"] is not None:
      print(jResponse["variable"])
```

The results above will print out the variable data if it's not null, but when it is null it fails.

I thought `is not None` would be the proper way to check for python null.

Edit - Request response:

```
    "response": {
        "variable1": value,
        "variable2": value,
        "variable3": value,
        "section1": {
            "variable1": value,
            "variable2": null,
```

The variable2 in section 1 is the variable I'm checking for and can sometimes be null. All of the other variables are being responded just fine.

Comment: You want `if jResponse.get("variable"):` instead.

Comment: Let me try that. Is that documented in python requests anywhere?

Comment: Edit above for the response coming back. All other variables return fine and I'm collecting all of their data. The section1:variable2 is the one that can be null and the one I need to check on and the one causing me issues. How would the .get() be adjusted to check that variable?

Answer (score 1):

You should check that jResponse is also not None:

```
if jResponse is not None and jResponse["variable"] is not None:
```

Comment: I've added that. I also check for a 200 response to be sure it's a good response being returned. Same result though.

Answer (score 0):

I was finding that my check for status 200 OK wasn't in the correct place and that in fact I was getting a 408 timeout after my while loop started. So, even though I thought responses were coming back it was actually timing out during the data collection. I moved my 200 OK check up higher and now all responses and data collecting must pass the 200 OK check. I'm seeing it good now.